# ¿Cómo guardo un valor en un registro dword?

Tags: ensamblador, operador, programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
mov r10, 9
mov r11, 5
sub r11, 2
imul r11, 2
add r10, r11
```

Esto no me da error, pero luego tengo:

```
mov dword [row],r10
```

Y esta última línea sí, me da error:

> invalid combination of opcode and operands.

El caso que `row` tiene que tener un valor concreto, que es:

```
row = 9 + (5 - 2) * 2
```

... y no se cómo asignárselo.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mi mismo. Ya lo he sacado.

El error estaba en el `mov`, para que funcione es así:

```
mov [rowScreen],r10
```

Y ya funciona perfectamente.